# How do I set the primary display on rhel 6 with dual displays

Tags: linux, display, display-settings, rhel-6

I've got a lenovo T410 laptop running RHEL 6.3. When I plug it into my docking station I've got it setup to do dual display, but it insists on using the laptop as the primary display keeping the various gnome panels on the laptop screen. I'd like it to work the opposite, I'd like my larger external display to be the primary. How do I configure my system to work as such?
 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But if you just want to move your GNOME panels to another monitor do this:

1. right click on a GNOME Panel
2. Select 'Properties'
3. In 'General' tab: from the drop-down list of 'Orientation' combo:

   Select the MONITOR and the POSITION you want.

   <- This is the trick, since all positions for ALL monitors are listed here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a terminal:

`> xrandr`

It will list all your available displays.
In the first column of the list, the "output" name is shown. Locate the monitor you want as primary. (You can check e.g. the resolution in the lis to identify your monitor).

Now:

`> xrandr --output <Here comes the ID of your monitor> --primary`

E.g:

`> xrandr --output DP-1-2 --primary`

Hope this helped...